# String formatting under a certain character

Tags: java

I'm making a textbook indexer and I'm formatting the output file. there are periods between the word and its frequency.

desired textfile output:

```
word..............25:
word...............3:
word...............2:
```

I'm trying to get the lines to be aligned to the `:` but I can't get it under the semicolon if the numbers are more than 1 digit.

Does anybody have any ideas for java string formatting for the desired output?

for reference the biggest word is 23 characters and it's frequency is 1.

Comment: First try solving it yourself, and then if still stuck, post your attempt here in your question. This involves simple math and a for loop, and I have faith that you'll either come up with a solution or something very close if you try just a little.

Comment: Why would I need a for loop? I'm trying to use Java's String format function. So far I have this:
String.format("%s%23d:", getWord(),count ).replace(' ', '.') + lineNumbers;

I'm continuing to mess around with it but no dice.

Comment: Make sure the font you use for your text file is a non-proportional font which would be a font whose letters and characters each occupy the same amount of horizontal space otherwise achieving a descent lineup will be difficult. **Courier** or **MonoSpace821 BT** are such fonts.

Comment: @DevilsHnd: generally text in a text file is font-agnostic.

Comment: Please post the current code that you have and we can give you hints a to how to approach the problem. We're not going to hand you an answer to an obvious homework question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since in the comment, the OP attempted to use `String.format()`, here is an approach to consider. Rather than trying to get the number to align right with the "%23d", align the word and the count separately.

```
String.format("%-23s%2d:", getWord(), count);
```

The `%-23d` will format the `getWord()` in 23 spaces, left aligned, then the `%2d` will right align the "count".

Example output:

```
Hello...................9:
Goodbye................42:
whatever...............17:
```

Note I just used the same `.replace()` approach as the OP for quickness sake.

[See this attempt here at ideone.com](https://ideone.com/act29I)